# How do I permanently fix the time on a bootable USB key?

Tags: unity, live-usb

I noticed the time is about 7 hours off, If I fix it, restart the time will be off again, anyway to permanently fix the time on the USB Flash Drive?

Comment: What time zone does the USB drive think it is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is probably one of the following:

- you use two operating systems, one of which is configured to the internal clock to UTC and the other to your local time zone; or
- you use two operating systems with differring time zones set.

In either case, the alternate operating systems would try to fix the time, perhaps using NTP. The solution would be to settle on one of the two, UTC or local time zone. Of course it would also require that your USB live linux has support for persistant settings, as Saifallah indicated. More information on time management is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the "Startup Disk Creator" which is installed by default in Ubuntu & enable the option that preserves settings.

Comment: pretty sure I did that...